# parameters for use_device() openACC

Tags: gpu, openacc, cufft

Is it allowed to pass objects instead of a pointer to the following directive

## pragma acc host_data use_device(myobject)

here is the code , Pn is the object and Pn.P is the pointer to the array where data is stored

```
#pragma acc data pcopyin( rank,N )
{
#pragma acc host_data use_device( Pn )
    {


        cufftPlan1d( &plan, 1000 , CUFFT_Z2Z, 1 );

        cufftExecZ2Z( plan, (cufftDoubleComplex*)Pn.P, (cufftDoubleComplex *)Pn.P, CUFFT_FORWARD );

     
    }
}
```

runing gives Seg Fault

Answer (score 1):

Try "host_data use_device( Pn.P )" so that "P"'s device address is used.

When you pass "Pn.P" as an argument, you're accessing "Pn" on the host to get the address of "P".  Hence by putting "Pn" in the host_data region, the code is using the device address which in turn causes the segv.

Comment: I tried it actually, the compiler does not like it , it gives the follwoing error
 error: expected a ")"
 #pragma acc host_data use_device( Pn.P )

Comment: Can you post a reproducer or send one to PGI Customer Service (trs@pgroup.com) and ask them to forward it to me?

Comment: sure, will do it today

Answer (score 0):

using version PGI 18.1 solves this issue